# Apply Compose compiler transformations to inspect them

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to learn about the how Compose UI interacts with the Compose Runtime but it is pretty hard to follow Compose UI's source code without the compiler transformations being visible (i.e. where it puts `$composer.start(Restart|Replaceable|etc)Group`, the `changed` parameter and such).

I was wondering if there is some tool or compiler flag that I can compile with to see the source code after the compiler applies all of its `@Composable` transformations.